# Laravel query returns empty, Database returns result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a very weird problem and will be grateful for some help.

I have a complicated Laravel query with a WhereIn() with a big array in it. It worked fine for a very long time but now the array apparently got too big and the query returns with no result. If I try the exact same query (toSql() Laravel function) with the big array, it works fine and I have my result.

On my local server, it works fine with no problems no matter the size of the whereIn array but on Live is broken so I'm thinking about a PHP or MySql setting or something similar.

Do you have any idea?

The query is:

```
$boardgamesCats = \App\ProductCategory::query()
            ->select(['product_categories.id AS cat_id','product_categories.menu_name AS cat_name', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as products_count') ])
            ->join('product_product_category','product_categories.id', '=', 'product_product_category.productCategory_id')
            ->where('product_categories.status','=','active')
            ->where('product_categories.parent_id', '=','1')
            ->whereIn('product_product_category.product_id',$productIds)
            ->groupBy('product_categories.id')
            ->orderBy('ord')
            ->get();
```

The problem is that $productIds array. Currently, there are 2005 items (ids) in it. If I put 1500 ids in it, for example, it works and returns what I need.

Comment: Can you drop some codes here? So that we can look into it and understand what could be the issue.

Comment: what is the default execution time on server ?

Answer (score 1):

did you add ->get()
at the end of your query ?

Example :

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
```

Comment: Yes, the query worked fine. It has get() at the end.

Comment: you can also use ->all() instead of ->get() and it returns you an array and not a collection if you prefer of course

or ->first() to retrieve the first element (collection)

Answer (score -1):

The correct way is to edit your php.ini file. Edit memory_limit to your desire value.

```
memory_limit = 2000M
```

OR

you can add this line in first line of your function

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Comment: Already doubled the memory_limit but didn't solve the issue.

Comment: did you try chunk in your query

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#chunking-results